# Error about "com.android.tools.r8.errors.b: A member class cannot also be a (non-member) local class at the same time."

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, dependencies, build.gradle

I am running a gradle-based sample .apk code in Android studio and I face this error:

```
com.android.tools.r8.errors.b: A member class cannot also be a (non-member) local class at the same time.
This is likely due to invalid EnclosingMethod and InnerClasses attributes:
[enclosingClass: Lcom/androidplot/xy/XYLegendWidget;, enclosingMethod: null]
[access : 2, inner: Lcom/androidplot/Plot$BufferedCanvas;, outer: Lcom/androidplot/Plot;, innerName: BufferedCanvas]
```

It is related to the implementation files('libs/androidplot-core-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar') in the build.gradle dependencies.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with the library. The content of the `InnerClasses` and `EnclosingMethod` attributes is described in *The Java® Virtual Machine Specification* sections [*4.7.6. The InnerClasses Attribute*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.6) and [*4.7.7. The EnclosingMethod Attribute*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.7). There is basically says that `EnclosingMethod` can only be present *if and only if it represents a local class or an anonymous class* and for a local class or an anonymous class the *outer* part of `InnerClasses` attribute must be `null` for that class. These properties are violated here.

As far as I can see there are many more recent version of the `androidplot-core` library available: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.androidplot/androidplot-core. Please try a more recent one to see if that doesn't solve the problem.